# Serialization strange results

Tags: java, serialization

I am novice in serialization.

I tryed to write simple code.
I got strange results. I don't understand it.

I have this code:

```
package easybudda.fakesizeof;

import java.io.*;

public class FakeSizeOf {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Object[] arr = { new Boolean(true), new Character('ы'), new Integer(13), new Long(69L), new Double(3.14) };
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);

        for ( Object obj : arr ) {
            outStream.reset();
            objOutStream.writeObject(obj);
            objOutStream.flush();
            System.out.println(obj.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + outStream.size());
        }

        System.out.println("\nUsing predefined methods:");
        outStream.reset();
        objOutStream.write(13);
        objOutStream.flush();
        System.out.println("write with int as data: " + outStream.size());

        outStream.reset();
        objOutStream.writeBoolean(false);
        objOutStream.flush();
        System.out.println("writeBoolean: " + outStream.size());

        outStream.reset();
        objOutStream.writeByte(1);
        objOutStream.flush();
        System.out.println("writeByte: " + outStream.size());

        outStream.reset();
        objOutStream.writeChar('ы');
        objOutStream.flush();
        System.out.println("writeChar: " + outStream.size());

        outStream.reset();
        objOutStream.writeDouble(3.14);
        objOutStream.flush();
        System.out.println("writeDouble: " + outStream.size());

        outStream.reset();
        objOutStream.writeInt(13);
        objOutStream.flush();
        System.out.println("writeInt: " + outStream.size());

        outStream.reset();
        objOutStream.writeLong(69L);
        objOutStream.flush();
        System.out.println("writeLong: " + outStream.size());
    }
}
```

output:

```
Boolean: 43
Character: 46
Integer: 77
Long: 51
Double: 53

Using predefined methods:
write with int as data: 3
writeBoolean: 3
writeByte: 3
writeChar: 4
writeDouble: 10
writeInt: 6
writeLong: 10
```

Can someone exlpain these results for me?

1.for example int - 4 byte(6-in output) - why?

2.Why Do from array so huge values?

Comment: 1. How to serialize int primitive? 2.Why Integer from array - 77 ?

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectOutputStream` prepends type information to everything it writes. See the [Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html), Protocol chapter:

> All primitive data written by classes is buffered and wrapped in block-data records, regardless if the data is written to the stream within a `writeObject` method or written directly to the stream from outside a `writeObject` method.

For example, `writeInt(13)` writes [119,4,0,0,0,13], which means

```
TC_BLOCKDATA,size=4 bytes,0,0,0,13.
```